# Show the dominant topic for each document under the document influence model

Tags: lda, topic-modeling

I am working on [DIM](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim_3.8.3/models/wrappers/dtmmodel.html) (Document Influence Model), and wonder how to show the dominant topic id for each document? I see no off-the-peg API for it. Can anyone help?